# Published version of VSTO app not icluding reference

Tags: c#, reference, vsto, publish, barcode

I'm building a Word VSTO add-in that will add a button to a custom ribbon to add a barcode using a popup form.  I'm using IronBarcode to generate the barcode image and paste it where the cursor is located.

When I run in Debug or Release mode in Visual Studio, it works flawlessly.  When I publish (using OneClick publish) and install the add-on, the ribbon loads, the popup form loads, but when I go to generate the barcode, nothing happens.  It doesn't crash and doesn't freeze.

Do I need to do something special to embed the IronBarcode reference into the installation files somehow?  Do I need to use the Windows Installed instead of OneClick?  I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: To be clear, does this happen when you publish/install to your own set?

Comment: Use Event Viewer to see if you are getting any errors when code is run.

Comment: ΩmegaMan, my own "set" meaning the same computer that I develop on?  Yes.
@jdweng, Are you talking about the Windows Event Viewer?  If so, I didn't see any errors.

Comment: Are you using the clipboard?  If so can you paste into another application?

Comment: @jdweng, I'm saving the barcode as an image to a temp directory then opening that file with the built-in VSTO methods to add an InlineShape.  Again, it all works perfectly in the IDE.

Comment: Does file get saved?  Maybe file is just getting save in a different folder.

Comment: The picture doesn't get saved as it turns out.  Based on my code, the image gets created by IronBarcode, so the fact that it's not getting created leads me to believe that the IronBarcode reference is not working properly.  Is there something special about using references in a VSTO add-on?

Comment: See if this helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-retrieve-a-folder-by-name?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that all the required prerequisites (assemblies) were included in the add-in installer. Make sure you did all the steps described in the [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2019) article.

Comment: The prerequisites that I see in the list are just the standard .NET framework versions, the VSTO Runtime, and some SQL server and C++ libraries.  I don't see any of my NuGet packages in the list.

Comment: Libraries from NuGet packages should be included in the add-in installer. Do you see them on the end-user machine?